# Creating One-to-Many relation in a Single Table Inheritance SQLAlchemy model

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, sqlalchemy

I have created the models with a Single Table Inheritance in the code below using SQLAlchemy.
I am trying to create a One-to-Many relationship, where a `Directory` can contain many `Bookmarks` linked by the `Bookmark.id`.

I want the models to allow me to do the following:

1. `Directory.children` or `Bookmark.children` (only if the `Bookmark` is a `Directory`) will give me the `Bookmarks` it contains. (whether `Directory` or `Url`)
2. `Bookmark.parent`, `Directory.parent` or `Url.parent` will give me the parent `Directory` of the `Bookmark`, `Directory` or `Url`

This is my first time using Single Table Inheritance, so I am probably making a stupid mistake.

Currently I have the following issues I know of:

1. `Directory.children` gets the the parent directory.
2. `Directory.parent` gets the the children Directories, but doesn't include any urls.

This the code I have:

```py
class Bookmark(Base):

    __tablename__ = "Bookmark"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column(String(256))
    date_added = Column(DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    position = Column(Integer)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, sqlalchemy.ForeignKey("Bookmark.id"))
    type = Column(String)

    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_on": type, "polymorphic_identity": "bookmark"}

class Url(Bookmark):

    url = Column(String(500))
    icon = Column(String)
    icon_uri = Column(String)
    tags = Column(String(500))

    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_identity": "url"}

class Directory(Bookmark):

    children = relationship(
        "Bookmark",
        cascade="save-update, merge, delete",
        backref="parent",
        lazy=False,
        remote_side="Bookmark.id",
    )
    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_identity": "directory"}
```

**Edit:**

So I solved a big part of my issue, I don't know if this is the best way to go by doing it or not but here goes.

1. I switched the name of the relationship and its backref `children/parent` to `parent/children` as follows

```py
parent = relationship(
        "Bookmark",
        cascade="save-update, merge, delete",
        backref="children",
        lazy=False,
        remote_side="Bookmark.id",
    )
```

2. I changed the location of the relationship from within the `Directory` class to the `Bookmark` class.

But now the `Url` class also has a `.children` attribute.
Is there anyway to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved a big part of my problem by doing the following:

1. I switched the name of the relationship and its backref `children/parent` to `parent/children` as follows

```py
parent = relationship(
        "Bookmark",
        cascade="save-update, merge, delete",
        backref="children",
        lazy=False,
        remote_side="Bookmark.id",
    )
```

2. I changed the location of the relationship from within the `Directory` class to the `Bookmark` class.

But now the `Url` class also has a `.children` attribute. (which is something I don't want)
There might be a better solution out there, but for now I will have to do with this.